# Finding a greater string among two strings

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two Strings like

1. 59fc5478fb7dbd08703f2539
2. 59fc54d3fb7dbd08703f253a

What I am doing is creating a unique **chat id** among two users by concatenating their user ids
But the issue is id formed can be **a+b** or **b+a** am trying to find a method so that it represents that string **a** is greater or **b** so the result is always unique id.
what I tried:-

1. localeCompare()
2. lexical ordering

   ```
   let a="59fc5478fb7dbd08703f2539";
   let b="59fc54d3fb7dbd08703f253a"; 
   if(a>b){
          let chatId=a+b;
          }else{
                let chatId=b+a;
                }
   ```

> chatId formed is 59fc5478fb7dbd08703f253959fc54d3fb7dbd08703f253a

**When a and b values are interchanged**

```
 let a="59fc54d3fb7dbd08703f253a"; 
 let b="59fc5478fb7dbd08703f2539";
        if(a>b){
               let chatId=a+b;
               }else{
                     let chatId=b+a;
                     }
```

> chatId formed is 59fc54d3fb7dbd08703f253a59fc5478fb7dbd08703f2539

Actual code used

```
  let newChat = new Chat();
   newChat.from = user._id;
   newChat.towards = req.body.towards;
   if (req.body.towards > user._id) {
       newChat.chatId = req.body.towards + user._id;
   } else {
       newChat.chatId = user._id + req.body.towards;
   }
   newChat.message = req.body.message;
   newChat.save((err) => {
```

result saved are

> db.chats.find()

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5a034eeb16e42914fc3f9ff8"), "message" : "hi", "chatId" : "59fc54d3fb7dbd08703f253a59fc5478fb7dbd08703f2539", "towards" : ObjectId("59fc5478fb7dbd08703f2539"), "from" : ObjectId("59fc54d3fb7dbd08703f253a"), "time" : ISODate("2017-11-08T18:37:31.308Z"), "__v" : 0 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5a034f3a16e42914fc3f9ff9"), "message" : "hello!", "chatId" : "59fc5478fb7dbd08703f253959fc54d3fb7dbd08703f253a", "towards" : ObjectId("59fc54d3fb7dbd08703f253a"), "from" : ObjectId("59fc5478fb7dbd08703f2539"), "time" : ISODate("2017-11-08T18:38:50.247Z"), "__v" : 0 }
```

according to lexical ordering the result should be unique but am getting two different results
Any help would be great thanks

Comment: Where did 59fc5456fb7dbd08703f2538 come from?

Comment: @TurtlesAllTheWayDown its a `_id` from mongoose

Comment: But it is neither a or b. You're just concatenating strings, correct?

Comment: @TurtlesAllTheWayDown yes concatenating in a unique way! but getting two different results when a and b are interchanged,updated question

Comment: You say let a="59fc54d3fb7dbd08703f253a"; and let b="59fc5478fb7dbd08703f2539"; so where did "59fc5456fb7dbd08703f2538" come from? That is what I am asking.

Comment: That formattig is "unusual" ( i could not work with that ...)

Comment: When i checked, i am getting same concatenated result for your both code.

Comment: @kgangadhar checked again getting different results

Comment: @JonasW. please if you can suggest a better way?

Comment: @kgangadhar JavaScript and ECMAScript difference?

Comment: Don't know. lets see what others will say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these are MongoDB IDs they are hex numbers. You could just compare them as numbers:

```
const a = '59fc5478fb7dbd08703f2539'
const b = '59fc54d3fb7dbd08703f253a'

const code = parseInt(a, 16) > parseInt(b, 16) ? a + b : b + a

console.log(code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) should do the trick here (without the optional locale parameter).

`"a".localeCompare("b")` will return a negative index when `a` comes first, a positive index when `b` comes first, and 0 when they are the same.